# Consuming C++ Native code and DLLs in windows C# app

Tags: c#, c++, .net, native, managed

I know this has been asked a bunch of times, but I think I have a bit of a twist on it.

I have a win32 c++ app that uses an sdk from another company. That sdk uses several dll files and even some exe files that I don't have the source code for and am not even really sure on how they have been compiled.

I do have the source code to their demo showing how to use the sdk.

I am able to build the demo and run it just fine on my computer.

I would like to use the sdk in a windows c# application. I am fine restricting it to a 32 bit application.

I am using Visual Studio 2015. When I open their demo it does have to import it, so the maker of it must have made it using a previous version of Visual Studio 2015, but I can't be sure.

I created a Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows) project. This created the standard Class1.cpp and .h files.

I then created my Blank App (Universal Windows) application project. I then added a reference in the application project to the runtime component project.

At this point I added code to create an instance of Class1 in my application. I set a break point in the Class1 constructor and debug the app. It stops on my break point like it should, so I know I have the connection between the app and the component working.

Next I import code into the runtime component. This code includes adding include files to the sdk. I also have to add the sdk.lib file to the linker. I added the include directories where all the .h files are.

I don't make any calls to the sdk stuff at this point at all yet.

When I debug the app now I get an exception as soon as I try to instanciate Class1. It doesn't let me debug into the constructor or anything.

The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I have looked through all of the details of the exception and it doesn't give any indications of what module it is looking for.

I have added all of the sdk files in the .bin folder of the sdk. That includes many dlls and exes and other files. I add them to the component project as content. All of the files are being copied to the final output folder where the app exe lives.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Try fusion log viewer to figure out what module is failing to load.

Comment: You say "app.exe" but then also "Windows Runtime". UWP Apps are highly restricted in what they can access for security reasons, and don't really output exes. Perhaps you should just make a standard .NET application?

Comment: I would like to just make a regular .NET C++ DLL that can be shared with a regular .NET C# Application, but could not see a proper wizard template to use when creating the apps. When I made the none windows runtime DLL it didn't have the C# sharable Class1. If you can tell me which templates to use in VS2015 I would use your answer.

Comment: @Millie Smith what is fusion log viewer and how do I use it?